# Opencart website loads very slow

Tags: mysqli, opencart2.x

[addiszone](http://www.addiszone.com) is running very slow. Its taking almost 60 sec to load a page. I looked into the catalog/controller/common/header.php file. It is fetching till Level 3. I want to optimize the code.

I found one [in this opencart forum](http://forum.%20forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=190&t=166800)
But its for opencart 1.5+ I need for Opencart 2.2.0.0
Since 5 days I am facing this problem. Please help me.

Right now its loading very slow. If I have more products, it will take loads of time.

Answer (score 1):

https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.addiszone.com/ybDctbCa

Here you can see how fast your site loads and what to optimize in it. Right off the bat I can tell you that you need to enable GZIP compression, use leverage browser caching and minify HTML and CSS. Another thing you should do is enable PHP 7 if your host supports it. Luckily, all of those things can be done by putting a few simple lines of code into your htaccess.
First of all, open your htaccess and change your php version to 7 if you haven't. the code for that is:
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php .php5 .php4 .php3

I have added it right at the top of my file. Next, I've pasted some code into pastebin, you can just copy it and insert it into your htaccess http://pastebin.com/VUsxi84k

Paste that code somewhere below RewriteEngine On and all its rules. Then test your site again. Hope my answer was useful :)